# onitemclicklistener does not work after fragment is executed

Tags: android, android-fragments

my problem is that as soon as i call a fragment in my main layout, the fragment is called in the frame, but after that, the onitemclick listener stops working. what is that i missed ?
the main.java

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mDrawerMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerMenu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.custom_menu_list, mDrawerMenu));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    //Action bar on item click events
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_icon:
                // create intent to perform web search for this planet
                Log.d("Hello","Menu clicked");
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Hello", String.valueOf(position));
            //Get the option name and compare
            TextView text = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            String MenuName = text.getText().toString();
            Log.d("Click", MenuName);
            if(position == 0){
                Log.d("Click","Home Clicked");
                // update the main content by replacing fragments

                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment, String.valueOf(position));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
            else if(position == 1){
                Log.d("Click","News Clicked 2");
            }


            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the menugragment which calls the layout.

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sports, container, false);
    }

}
```

Now, as it is replaced in the frame in main (when the position is 0, the fragment is called),after that if 1 is called, the onitemclicklistener does not work. why is that ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you see the messages logs in the logcat?

Comment: no , no logs after the fragment is called

Comment: Which is your last log, Log.d("Click","Home Clicked"); ?

Comment: no home clicked, it does not reconginze the onitemclicklistener

Comment: hmm. is it that,i again need to define the onitemclicklistener in Menufragement class?

Comment: Do you add the listener to the listview, like listview.addOnItemClickListener(yourlistener)?

Comment: Did you put ?

    android:focusable="false"
    
    android:clickable="false"

in layout. For all textviews,buttons etc.

Comment: I believe you should check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899904/solved-onitemclicklistener-on-a-listview-inside-a-fragment-not-working

Comment: @Owehbeh, my listener is in the main.java , i have no listener inside the fragment Menufragment

Comment: Can you post the full code in your main.java?

Comment: @Chefes, yes i have posted the main.java

Comment: Can you check this post?, maybe is the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369028/fragments-are-not-loaded-from-navigation-drawer-click-listener

Comment: add mani.xml please?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan, i addeed the mainxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment, String.valueOf(position));
```

to

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, String.valueOf(position));
```

You should replace the content_frame not the drawer_layout

Comment: if i replaced the drawer layout then still the listview works, why is that ?

Comment: If listview is working, then there should be action right? then onclick also should work, whether onclick is working..? ans is no right.